# After quiting my job, can an employer tell me I can't be friends with the family of a client?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, socializing, bullying

I am in doubt if my former employer can really keeping me from staying in contact with a patient that I took care of when I worked for them.

Both the patient family and myself really want to stay in contact on a personal basis. I do not want to try to provide any type of nursing service or advise to them at all.

I signed a *no compete clause* and the way it was explained to me was that I couldn't work for a competing company for a period of 2 years. *There was never any mention of not being able to maintain a friendship.*

How can i approach this situation? How can i manage this position without risking my professional image?

Comment: have a lawyer double check the no-compete clause, don't rely on the internet for legal information

Comment: I am not a laywer and indeed you should seek legal advice. Let me put it this way though. Even if your intent is for the purposes of friendship with zero business intent, the former employer can construe your contact with that person as being a violation of a non-compete. Sorry that it's 2 years non-compete, if it was 6 or 12 months it would be more amenable. My personal opinion.